# Cannot create docker image for angular app

Tags: angular, docker

I'm trying to create a docker image for angular app and managed to do that with few toy projects.

I should mention that my experience with both docker and angular is pretty poor.

If i try to run npm run build from the terminal inside my project it successfully creates the dist folder.

As I've understood the docker file for an angular app is made from two parts, the first stage is for building the angular app where the second is for actually creating the docker image.

I'm setting the working dir to be :

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
```

After I'm setting proxies and runnning npm i and npm run build.

On the latest step where I copy all the files generated by the npm build in the path /usr/src/app/dist it fails to find it and it fails the build:

```
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

What I think it happens is that somewhere it fails to build the dist folder or is removed.

If I try to run the Dockerfile without the last cmd (COPY) and run the image, if I do `docker exec -it hedgehog-front-end bash` and try to go to /usr/src/app/ this is empty.

The docker commands I run from command line are:

```
docker build --rm -t hedgehog-fe .

docker run --rm -d --name hedgehog-front-end -p 8888:80/tcp hedgehog-fe
```

but obviously it fails on the build

also tried to run the build without --rm flag, failed as well. As to my knowledge the --rm flag removes the container once it exits.

The full Dockerfile is:

```
FROM node:10-alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

ENV http_proxy http://192.168.150.242:3128
ENV https_proxy http://192.168.150.242:3128
ENV no_proxy 192.168.151.171,local*,127.0.0.1,172.19.0.3

RUN npm config set proxy http://192.168.150.242:3128
RUN npm config set https-proxy http://192.168.150.242:3128

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build
# also tried with: RUN npm run build  --output-path=/usr/src/app/dist but with little success

RUN pwd

FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine

RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
```

And the docker logs are the following:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.052MB
Step 1/14 : FROM node:10-alpine AS builder
 ---> 9dfa73010b19
Step 2/14 : WORKDIR /usr/src/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 75922f5045ea
Step 3/14 : COPY . .
 ---> 8605405dd225
Step 4/14 : ENV http_proxy http://192.168.150.242:3128
 ---> Running in cda1703a159d
Removing intermediate container cda1703a159d
 ---> c89d7918e24f
Step 5/14 : ENV https_proxy http://192.168.150.242:3128
 ---> Running in 51597119b85f
Removing intermediate container 51597119b85f
 ---> 99104b4ceeec
Step 6/14 : ENV no_proxy 192.168.151.171,local*,127.0.0.1,172.19.0.3
 ---> Running in 92c895a8bbab
Removing intermediate container 92c895a8bbab
 ---> 1492be836516
Step 7/14 : RUN npm config set proxy http://192.168.150.242:3128
 ---> Running in a2c0191f05c5
Removing intermediate container a2c0191f05c5
 ---> 6a26b7e44a3a
Step 8/14 : RUN npm config set https-proxy http://192.168.150.242:3128
 ---> Running in 514694cb5b9e
Removing intermediate container 514694cb5b9e
 ---> 65567143581a
Step 9/14 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in a7d3375c0265
...
...
...
Removing intermediate container a7d3375c0265                                               
 ---> 274f7f2fa911                                                                         
Step 10/14 : RUN npm run build --output-path=/usr/src/app/dist                             
 ---> Running in c302f6ffdcbe                                                              

> hedgehog@0.0.0 build /usr/src/app                                                        
> ng build                                                                                 


Date: 2019-07-25T09:35:46.279Z                                                             
Hash: 91334de448ec3f98f32f                                                                 
Time: 21001ms                                                                              
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 86.7 kB [initial] [rendered]                      
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 240 kB [initial] [rendered]   
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]            
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 347 kB [initial] [rendered]               
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 7.38 MB [initial] [rendered]              
Removing intermediate container c302f6ffdcbe                                               
 ---> e686f496c94c                                                                         
 ---> e686f496c94c
Step 11/14 : RUN pwd
 ---> Running in 7fd1c2612469
/usr/src/app
Removing intermediate container 7fd1c2612469
 ---> 4b5e572e2260
Step 12/14 : FROM nginx:1.15.8-alpine
 ---> b411e34b4606
Step 13/14 : RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6db439d21fe8
Step 14/14 : COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/d807f3937fc7f50f75a1aad123648730eecfb8c59da3afda634eedf9f0e43c55/merged/usr/src/app/dist: no such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

well I had the /dist folder in my .dockerignore

removed it from it and now it works